# socket programming client server java

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm trying to implement a TCP send and receive program between a client and a server. They exchange info. continuously by using a loop. The client send a message first. Without the loop the program work but with the loop, it doesn't. Below are the programs:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // SERVER

    try
    {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(11);
        Socket s1 = null;
        int i=0;
        while (true)
        {
            s1 = s.accept();
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s1.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s1.getOutputStream()));
            String m;
            while ((m=b.readLine())!=null)
            {
                i++;
                System.out.print(m);
                p.print("reply"+i);
            }
        }

    }catch(IOException e){}

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // CLIENT

    Socket s = new Socket("192.168.100.3",11);
    int i = 0;

    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

    p.print("msg"+i);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    while (true){
        PrintWriter p1 = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

        BufferedReader b1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String m;
        while((m=b1.readLine())!=null)
        {               
            System.out.print(m);
            p1.print("msg"+i);
        }
        i++;
        p1.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to flush after p.print("reply"+i); ?

Comment: nope, i'll try it and let u know

Comment: i think the problem is with the socket being closed.. the socket is closed after each iteration in the while(true) loop, thats why the msg are not sent and received..if I close the socket after the loop, eclipse give me an error

Answer (score 0):

When you use `readLine()` it reads up to the end of line.

However, `print(x)` doesn't write a newline.

If you write and flush a `println(x)` there is be a new line at the end of your text to read.

Comment: the problem is that flow of control just doesnt go in the loop : while(br.readline!=null)   of the server.. maybe the problem is with the client

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense to loop and accept on the same socket? as in:

```
Socket s1 = null;
while (true) {
  s1 = s.accept();
```

Also, I don't think it would work on port 11 as you have in your code there. Try port numbers above 1024, those are not privileged.

Comment: yes, this socket can be a different socket depending on the different clients that want to connect to the server..

Answer (score 0):

This code will just deadlock. Both ends are reading. Somebody needs to send something first, ensuring that it is line-terminated so that the peer's `readLine()` call will return.

Comment: yes, the client sends a message first when the connection is accepted by the server using s.accept() and I think the message (msg+i) is line terminated...